# How to display jquery popup window with a text area and several radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display a popup window which will ask user to select one from given radio button options(let's say 3 radio button options). Or type something in the given text area(**only one can be done**)

Once user clicked OK button in the popup window, I want to pass selected radio button value or text in the text area to a variable.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you want the popup to be a separate browser window, or just a box overlay (dialog box) in the same browser window?

Comment: it would be better if you post the code you tried

Comment: I'm going to assume that you've actually attempted this task. Please post the results of your effort.

Comment: I just need a box overlay (dialog box) in the same browser window. I haven't try any code since I have no idea how to do this. Just give me an example so I can use it in my code

Comment: @Roshanck in that case you simply refer http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ demos and as far as you are afraid of passing selected radio button value to the page behind the popup you can still access the element with it's id because it will be there in the same DOM

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a lightbox approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lightbox or jquery tools [overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html) to create the form, and then put the variable back in a callback.