# How to use jQuery overlay to get radio buttons to the popup window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am following this tutorial and designed and alert window(including online demo),
http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

I could modify the source code and **added radio buttons to the alert message**.Source code is given bellow(you don't have to go through the whole code.Just see the place where I have added radio buttons and place where I access the value of the radio button),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
   This is a jQuery Tools standalone demo. Feel free to copy/paste.
   http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/

   Do *not* reference CSS files and images from flowplayer.org when in
   production Enjoy!
-->
<head>
  <title>jQuery Tools standalone demo</title>

    <!-- include the Tools -->
  <script src="jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

  <!-- standalone page styling (can be removed) -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/media/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="/media/css/standalone.css"/>

  <style>
    .modal {
    background-color:#fff;
    display:none;
    width:350px;
    height:250px;
    padding:15px;
    text-align:left;
    border:2px solid #333;

    opacity:0.8;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
  }

  .modal h2 {
    background:url(/media/img/global/info.png) 0 50% no-repeat;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 45px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    font-size:20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body><!-- the triggers -->
<p>
  <button class="modalInput" rel="#yesno">Yes or no?</button>
  <button class="modalInput" rel="#prompt">User input</button>
</p>

<!-- yes/no dialog -->
<div class="modal" id="yesno">
  <h2>This is a modal dialog</h2>

  <p>
    You can only interact with elements that are inside this dialog.
    To close it click a button or use the ESC key.
  </p>

  <!-- yes/no buttons -->
  <p>
    <button class="close"> Yes </button>
    <button class="close"> No </button>
  </p>
</div>



<!-- user input dialog -->
<div class="modal" id="prompt">
  <h2>This is a modal dialog</h2>

  <p>
    You can only interact.
  </p>

  <!-- input form. you can press enter too -->
  <form>
    //Added radio buttons
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male"> Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female"> Female<br />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
  <br />

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({

      // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
      mask: {
        color: '#ebecff',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
      },

      closeOnClick: false
  });

    var buttons = $("#yesno button").click(function(e) {

      // get user input
      var yes = buttons.index(this) === 0;

      // do something with the answer
      triggers.eq(0).html("You clicked " + (yes ? "yes" : "no"));
  });

    $("#prompt form").submit(function(e) {

      // close the overlay
      triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();

      // get user input
      var input = $("input", this).val(); // this input value always return 'male' as the output  



      // do something with the answer
      triggers.eq(1).html(input);

      // do not submit the form
      return e.preventDefault();
  });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This demo has two alert windows. I am talking about the alert message which has the text input.In my example I have remove text input and added two radio buttons.**
**But when I click the 'submit' button It always return me 'male' as the output**
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem? I need to get the output of the radin buttons to variable 'input'

Comment: Refer this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011743/how-to-display-jquery-popup-window-with-a-text-area-and-several-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1):

Use this to pop up the box. In the HTML keep the radio button.

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td class="web_dialog_title">Email this Article</td>
     <td class="web_dialog_title align_right">
        <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
<TR><TD>
```

Use radio button.

```
</TD></TR>
 </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e)
  {
     ShowDialog(false);
     e.preventDefault();
  });



  $("#btnClose").click(function (e)
  {
     HideDialog();
     e.preventDefault();

  });

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 27) {
     HideDialog(); }
});

 });

function ShowDialog(modal)
{
  $("#overlay").show();
  $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);

  if (modal)
  {
     $("#overlay").unbind("click");
  }
  else
  {
     $("#overlay").click(function (e)
     {
        HideDialog();
     });
  }
}

function HideDialog()
{
  $("#overlay").hide();
  $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you changed text type input with radio type input . so you must change

```
var input = $("input", this).val();
```

with this one

```
var input = $("input:checked", this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

perdickss provides a very good answer for this example.
But that will not work if you have multiple inputs in the page. So you should use something like this:

```
 var input = $("input[name=FIELD_NAME]:checked", this).val();
```

Where FIELD_NAME is the name you have for the inputs you want to check. In this case the code would look like:

```
var input = $("input[name=sex]:checked", this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your code:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male"> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female"> Female<br />

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

There are two input fields in your `#prompt form`, so when you get value with this code:

```
var input = $("input", this).val();
```

You will always get value of first matched element (which is `male`).

All you have to do is specify checked input using `:checked` selector, I suggest you additionally to add input's name:

```
var input = $("input[name=sex]:checked", this).val();
```